# Checking Python containers for an exact value instead of an equal value

Tags: python, python-2.7, comparison, containers, contains

Here's some example code:

```
>>> l = [ [0], [1], [2] ]
>>> z = [0]
>>> print z == l[0]
True
>>> print z is l[0]
False
>>> print z in l
True
```

Here's the behavior I'd like to be able to use:

```
>>> print z in l
False
>>> print l[0] in l
True
```

I know that I can do something like this, but it doesn't feel Pythonic.

```
>>> print any([z is i for i in l])
False
```

I feel like there could be an *is in* operator or something that I'm missing. What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: The last method you showed is how you're going to have to go about this, there is no such operator equivalent to `in` but using `is` instead of `==`. Except drop the `[]` so it can [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), instead of evaluating the full list of items first.

Comment: How could  `l[0] in l` not be True?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Because l[0] is in l. l is a list and quite naturally, an element in that list is in that list.

Comment: @rady, missed the not,  `z = l[0]` creates a reference

Comment: `z == l[0]` is true, but `z is l[0]` is not. `l[0] is l[0]`, on the other hand, is of course true. I meant to illustrate that what I'm looking to accomplish is finding whether an exact match is contained rather than an equal object.

Comment: @Pineapple, net dropped before I could finish, using `is` will not always work checking identity either, `l = [ "foo","bar"];a = "foo";a is l[0]-> True`

Comment: How would that not be the expected behavior for string and numeric literals?